# Why do i keep gettig an error message o this code

Tags: python, data-science, pearson-correlation

this is an IBM skill lab code. try running it and keeps getting a error

```
pearson_coef, p_value = stats.pearsonr(df['city-mpg'], df['price'])
print("The Pearson Correlation Coefficient is", pearson_coef, " with a P-value of P = ", p_value)
```

error message

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [71], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 pearson_coef, p_value = stats.pearsonr(df['city-mpg'], df['price'])
      2 print("The Pearson Correlation Coefficient is", pearson_coef, " with a P-value of P = ", p_value)

NameError: name 'stats' is not defined
​
```

Comment: I read this as the pearsonr method is in something called stats. Have you got an `import stats` somewhere before this call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to import stats - which without knowing what package you're trying to use - I would assume is the `stats` package from `scipy`

Add the following line at the top of your cell or file

```
# Import statistical package from Scipy
from scipy import stats
```